# Чат, нагрузка, разгрузка

Tags: php, чат, sql, mysql

Как организовать бд для, да и сам чат? Постоянно обновлять блок чата - так это большая нагрузка. Есть идея про дополнительное поле в таблице сообщение в мускуле, которое будет информировать о том, прочитано ли оно, и загружать только их, но это опять же нагрузка на сервер. Помогите советом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть AJAX, вот при помощи него можно делать запрос к БД не перезагружая страницу.

В БД в таблице хранить определённое количество последних сообщений, например 100, в каждой записи должно содержаться !серверное! время получения сообщения.

Когда юзер отправляет сообщение на сервер то в таблице затирается первая запись и добавляется новая с его сообщением + время получения сообщения сервером, в это-же время, с определённым интервалом, Java-Script на страницах пользователя, с определённым интервалом, например 15 секунд, делает запрос к БД на наличие нового сообщения, при этом в переменной он уже хранит !серверное! время получения последнего сообщения, и если есть более новое то загружает его, дописывая новый <div>Arc: Всем привет!</div> в другой <div></div> содержащий все сообщения. Таким образом не нужно загружать каждый раз ВСЕ сообщения с сервера, каждый клиент будет получать лишь последнее сообщение либо новое при его наличии.

Конечно это возможно не верная концепция, так как я с Java-Script на Вы.

Comment: Так, я наконец-то вчитался в ваш ответ. Идея про переменную мне определенно понравилась, спасибо вам.

Comment: @Arc, да, объяснять у меня плохо получается :) Я вот не подумал, в JAva-Script не очень разибраюсь, поэтому возможно не получится держать в памяти переменную, ведь после обновления страницы с чатом (например пользователь перешел на другую страницу сайта) значения сбросятся, да и все сообщения придётся загружать заново, хотя это в любом случае лучше чем через каждые 10 сек. загружать все эти сообщения у всех пользоветелей.

Comment: Не вижу проблемы в том, чтобы обновлять эту переменную в бд

Answer (score 2):

Чат удобно держать в памяти и не ходить за чтением в базу.

Историю удобно складировать в файлах как это MIRC делает.

И не нужен тут никакой mysql...

Comment: а мне не удобно.

Answer (score 1):

[пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/41223/) - не совсем про таблицу, скорее про общую организацию чата